# What is the difference between using a ServiceBusMessageBatch and sending multiple messages in a TransactionScope?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, transactionscope

Using `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`.

I want to send multiple messages to Azure Service Bus in one transaction. I'm fine with the limit of 100 messages per transaction.

What are the pros and cons of these two approaches?

**TransactionScope**
*Multiple single-message send operations in a TransactionScope.*

```
public async Task SendMessages(IEnumerable<ServiceBusMessage> messages, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);

    var tasks = messages.Select(m => _serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(m, cancellationToken));
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    transaction.Complete();
}
```

**ServiceBusMessageBatch**
*Single send operation, send a ServiceBusMessageBatch.*

```
public async Task SendMessages(IEnumerable<ServiceBusMessage> messages, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var batch = await _serviceBusSender.CreateMessageBatchAsync(cancellationToken);

    foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        if (!batch.TryAddMessage(message))
            throw new Exception("...");
    }

    await _serviceBusSender.SendMessagesAsync(batch, cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the TransactionScope approach will do one request per message to ASB. If that's correct, then this is maybe a question of message size versus performance? If messages don't exceed batch size limit, use batch sending, because it's more performant and less chatty?

Comment: For the record, this is to be used in a polling publisher setup. So the number of messages sent per "run" isn't important. Doing `batch.TryAddMessage` until it fails or all messages are added, then sending, seems like a good option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A batch is a way to send multiple messages to the broker without exceeding the total size constraint as, during batch construction, the API will not add messages that would cause the batch size to exceed the maximum allowed. That's what a batch is for, for safety to ensure you don't get message size exception upon dispatching.

`TransactionScope` ensures that messages sent within the same transaction are all sent if successful or reverted if one of the messages fails.

With a batch, it's a single call to the broker. There are multiple concurrent calls to the broker with transaction scope, such as the number of send operations.

The benefit of the batch: a single call to the broker that will have no chance to fail due to too many messages grouped together and exceeding maximum size. This is handy when you have multiple messages ready to be sent.

The benefit of the transaction scope is when you need to dispatch messages but don't have them all available within the same instance or need to send in a fire-and-forget mode but still want to ensure those are sent atomically.

Comment: when you said *There are multiple concurrent calls to the broker with transaction scope*, that means if there is an exception, all messages in batch are rollback ?

Comment: If message operations are a part of the transaction, then yes. The incoming and outgoing messages (from a consumer perspective) will be rolled back.

Comment: Regarding the batch, it's just a way to group multiple messages into a single "envelope". A failure to send a batch would mean all messages in that batch would not be delivered.